# StopOnException for multicast is not working

Tags: apache-camel

What does multicast().stopOnException() does? I have written routes:

```
from("{{from.route}}").
        multicast().stopOnException().to("jms:queue:carservice","jms:queue:flightservice");

        from("jms:queue:carservice").throwException(new Exception("Car not working")).log("failed message");
        from("jms:queue:flightservice").log("flight message polled");
```

Even if i remove stopOnException, the output looks exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected in this use case, as the send operation to JMS works and does not fail (only if sending to JMS fails it will throw an exception and multicast will stop), so the multicast was successful. You can use InOut (request reply) over JMS and enable the `transferException` option but this requires to use Camel on both sides of JMS. And its also not a good advice to exchange data as Java serialized data (eg the exception).

If you use `direct` endpoint instead if you want the thrown exception to be propagated back to the multicast for it to fail.

Comment: But an exception is being thrown when the message is sent to carservice. I did not understand.  from("jms:queue:carservice").throwException(new Exception("Car not working")).log("failed message");

Comment: You are using JMS its not the same as a synchronous in-memory java method call etc such as the direct component. JMS makes it asynchronous